# How to include excerpt option on taxonomy category page?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, taxonomy, meta-boxes

I am trying to add an excerpt option to my category page, to display instead of my description.

So basically, I need a box on this screen which will be able to be used as preview text.

The code used to create this taxonomy is:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_cat_external' );

function create_product_cat_external() {
  register_taxonomy(
    'ExternalProducts',
    'products',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'External Products' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'externalproducts' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

and the box needs to be here:

[image: screenshot of the UI]

Comment: I would use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for this, unless the project requires you to specifically code it in at theme level. Is this an option for you? Ref: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: It could be an option, but It really is wanted by the user so they can add this on this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CMB2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/) plugin and put this in your **functions.php** for example:

```
    add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'yourprefix_register_taxonomy_metabox' );
    function yourprefix_register_taxonomy_metabox() {
        $prefix = 'yourprefix_term_';       

        $cmb_term = new_cmb2_box( array(
            'id'               => $prefix . 'edit',
            'object_types'     => array( 'term' ), // Tells CMB2 to use term_meta vs post_meta
            'taxonomies'       => array( 'products'), // Tells CMB2 which taxonomies should have these fields
            // 'new_term_section' => true, // Will display in the "Add New Category" section
        ) );

        $cmb_term->add_field( array(
            'name'       => __('Excerpt', 'default'),           
            'id'       => $prefix . 'excerpt',
            'type'     => 'wysiwyg',
            'on_front' => false,
        ) );
    }
```